# Delete All the records Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints if Main Table Entity is deleted

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms

How to delete records from multiple tables if main table’s entity is deleted as constraints is applied on all

**Scenario**

Let me give you a scenario: there is this main table called `Organization` or `TblOrganization`. This organization has branches which are in branch table called `tblBranch`, and these branches have multiple applications in a table  `tblApplication`. These applications in turn are used by multiple users stored in `tblUsers`.

What I want is: when I delete an organization, all the branches, applications and users related to it must be deleted also.

How I can apply that on a button click in asp.net web forms?

Right now this is my delete function which is very simple

```
Public void Delete(int? id)
{
    var str = ”DELETE FROM tblOrganization WHERE organizationId=”+ id ;
}
```

And my tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblOrganization
(
    OrganizationId int,
    OrganizationName varchar(255)
); 


CREATE TABLE tblApplication
(
     ApplicationId int,
     OrganizationId int,
     ApplicationName varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblBranches
(
    BranchId int, 
    OrganizationId int,
    BranchName varchar (255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblUsers
(
    userId int,
    OrganizationId int,
    UserName varchar(255)
);
```

Constraints are applied on all table like this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBranchs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblBranchs_tblOrganization] 
    FOREIGN KEY([OrganizationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblOrganization] ([OrganizationId])
```

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant it is, but have you looked into "ON DELETE CASCADE" ?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Let me study about that

Comment: You cannot "apply" this in ASP.NET - you need to define your **foreign key constraints** in the underlying database to have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set to on

Comment: @marc_s Dear that is not an issue right now I do understand that Thanks for reminding me

Comment: @marc_s How can I do that can you please give a bit example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the constraints on tblBranch, tblApplication, and tblUsers:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBranchs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblBranchs_tblOrganization] 
    FOREIGN KEY([OrganizationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblOrganization] ([OrganizationId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblApplication] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblApplication_tblBranchs] 
    FOREIGN KEY([BranchId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblBranchs] ([BranchId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUsers] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUsers_tblApplication] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblApplication] ([ApplicationId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now if you delete an organization, the database engine will delete all related child records automatically:

- If you delete an organization, all related records form tblBranch, tblApplication, and tblUsers will be deleted.
- If you delete a branch, all related records form tblApplication and tblUsers will be deleted.
- If you delete an Application, all related records form tblUsers will be deleted.
- If you delete a user, nothing else will be deleted.

Comment: I've a question will the cascade delete work if some one deletes the user? Because I don't want it work like that, it should only work when organization is deleted and as I see in this one it goes both was, so How can I restrict that

Comment: No, it only works in one way. From the parent to the children, not vice versa. So if you delete a user, nothing else will be deleted. See my updated answer for full explanation.

Comment: SORRY to disturb you again! I got that Than I've another question Let say this time its not the ADMIN, Its just a user who creates a branch and that branch have child branches how can I prevent him if he is going to delete the parent branch in the current case  of CASCADE DELETE the deletion  process will occur I want him only to delete the branch which has no child branches

Comment: It was very helpful regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "apply" this in ASP.NET - this is a **database concern** and you need to change your foreign key constraints to include `ON DELETE CASCADE` - something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBranchs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblBranchs_tblOrganization] 
    FOREIGN KEY([OrganizationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblOrganization] ([OrganizationId])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This means: if a row from `tblOrganization` is deleted, that delete will be *cascaded* down into the `tblBranchs` table, too, deleting all rows that have been referencing that orgnization. You can have these `ON DELETE CASCADE` settings over multiple foreign key constraints down to the `tblUsers` table.

Comment: and then how can I implement that in asp.net, Mean How can I send a call to that on button click

Comment: @user3515453: just simply delete the row from `tblOrganization` - SQL Server handles the rest

Comment: I've a question will the cascade delete work if some one deletes the user? Because I don't want it work like that, it should only work when organization is deleted and as I see in this one it goes both was, so How can I restrict that

Comment: No, it will **not** kick in when a user is deleted - the user has no "subordinate" entries that reference it with a FK constraint that uses `ON DELETE CASCADE`. With the FK constraints, you building up a directed graph - users references application and gets deleted when the application is deleted, application references branches and gets deleted when its branch is deleted, branch is referencing organization and gets deleted when it's referenced organization is deleted. It's a **one-way** thing - it doesn't work in the opposite direction....

Comment: SORRY to disturb you again! I got that Than I've another question Let say this time its not the ADMIN, Its just a user who creates a branch and that branch have child branches how can I prevent him if he is going to delete the parent branch in the current case  of CASCADE DELETE the deletion  process will occur I want him only to delete the branch which has no child branches

Comment: The `ON DELETE CASCADE` only works in the way I described it. You have no control over it, so you will have to implement that in your ASP code. When the user tried to delete a branch, first check the database to see if it has any children. If it has no children, then delete it and show a success message. If it has children, show a message like **This branch has sub-branches. You cannot delete it.**.

Comment: It was very helpful regards